# Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision Failed to Install

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I'm just try to install ProjectOxford.Vision from Nuget but its error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision 1.0.213'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.         0

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed as of release [1.0.296](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision/1.0.296)